# How to count occurrences of a substring within string fast with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, string, benchmarking

I have a text file sized 300MB, I want to count the occurrences of each 10,000 substrings in the file. I want to know how to do it fast.

Now, I use the following code:

```
content = IO.read("path/to/mytextfile")
Word.each do |w|
  w.occurrence = content.scan(w.name).size
  w.save
end
```

Word is an ActiveRecord class.

It took me almost 1 day to finish the counting. Is there anyway to do it faster? Thanks.

Edit1:
Thank you again. I am running rails 2.3.9. The `name` filed of words table contains what I am searching for, and it contains only unique values. Instead of using `Word.each`, I use batch(1000 rows a time) load. It should help.

I rewrited the whole code with the idea from bpaulon. Now it only took a few hours to finish the counting.

I profiled the new version code, now the largest time costing methods are utf8 encode supported string truncating code

```
def truncate(n)
  self.slice(/\A.{0,#{n}}/m)
end
```

and characters counting code

```
def utf8_length
  self.unpack('U*').size
end
```

Any other faster methods to replace them?

Comment: Well you could always divide the file and scan it in separeta threads...

Comment: Are these sub-strings always white-space delimited?  Or can some of them contain spaces?

Comment: not white-space delimited. some may contain spaces.

Comment: bpaulon, can you tell me how in details? My code can use one core of the cpu, and the core is always 100% occupied.

Comment: I did it. I divided the Word table into two parts! It counts one part each for a thread, now the cpu usage is 100%, instead of 50%.

Comment: It seems jruby can do it faster: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/212074

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could approach this problem differently

You do not need to scan the file this many times, you could create a db, like in [mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/) or [mysql](http://www.mysql.com/), and for each word you find, you fetch the db for it and then adds on some "counter" field.

You could ask me "but then I will have to scan my database a lot and it could take a lot more". Well, sure you wouldn't ask this, but it won't take more time because databases are focused in IO, besides you could always [index it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29).

---

**EDIT:** There is no way to delimit at all?? Let's say that where you have the a Word.name string you really holds a (not simple) regex. Could the regex contain the \n? Well, if the regex can contain any value, you should estimate the maximum size of string the regex can fetch, double it, and scan the file by that ammount of chars but moving the cursor by that number.

Lets say your estimate of the maximum your regex could fetch it is like 20 chars nad your file has from 0 to 30000 chars. You pass each regex you have from 0 to 40 chars, then again from 20 to 60, from 40 to 80, etc...

You should also hold the position you found of your smaller regex so it wouldn't repeat it.

Finally, this solution seems to be not worth the effort, your problem may have a greater solution based on what that regexes are, but it will be faster than invoke scan Words.count times your your 300Mb string.

Comment: I did not scan the file. I loaded it first, then scanned the content.

Comment: I meant the "scan" method of ruby, sorry for the ambiguity

Comment: You see, for each word in your db you fire the method "scan" on the whole file, and you should be doing the opposite (in my opinion), for each word on the file you look for it on the db and adds one to its counter

Comment: I get what you mean now. It will be a nice solution, but my problem is that they are not WORDS I am counting for. They are strings and no delimiter to break the whole file into "each word".

Comment: Edited my answer. May I ask you what is the format of this "substrings"?

Comment: I get it. I even did it one time before for a word segmentation program. First, I divided the substrings by length into hashes, then fetched a part of the content of the big file to compare with the substrings of equal length, then moved to next character position ... It should be much faster. Then only problem now is that I need to write much more code! Thanks!

Comment: The substrings are WORDS, in fact, but Chinese words。Words in Chinese are not separated by spaces. I said they were not words just want to make the problem simpler, please forgive me.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of `scan` creates an array, counts the size of it, then throws it away. If you have a lot of occurrences of the substring inside a big file, you will create a big array temporarily, potentially burning up CPU time with memory management, but that should still run pretty quickly, even with 300MB.

Because Word is an ActiveRecord class, it is dependent on the schema and any indexes in your database, plus any issues your database server might be having. If the database is not optimized or is responding slowly or the query used to retrieve the data is not efficient, then the iteration will be slow. You might find it a lot faster to grab groups of `Word` so they are in RAM, then iterate over them.

And, if the database and your code are running on the same machine, you could be suffering from resource constraints like having only one drive, not enough RAM, etc.

Without knowing more about your environment and hardware it's hard to say.

---

EDIT:

> I can grab the substrings into an array/hash first, then add the count results to the array or hash, and write the results back to database after all the counting is done. You think it be faster, right?

No, I doubt that will help a lot, and, without knowing where the problem lies all you might do is make the problem worse because you'll have to load 10,000 records as objects from the database, then build a 10,000 element hash or array which will also be in memory along with the DB records, then write them out.

Ruby will only use a single core, currently, but you can gain speed by using Ruby 1.9+. I'd recommend [installing RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) and letting it manage your Ruby. Be sure to read the instructions on that page, then run `rvm notes` and follow those directions.

What is your Word model and the underlying schema and indexes look like? Is the database on the same machine?

---

EDIT: From looking at your table schema, you have no indexes except for `id` which really won't help much for normal look-ups. I'd recommend presenting your schema on Stack Overflow's sibling site https://dba.stackexchange.com/ and explain what you want to do. At a minimum I'd add a key to the text fields to help avoid full table scans for any searches you do.

What might help more is to read: [Retrieving Multiple Objects in Batches](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects) from "Active Record Query Interface".

Also, look at the SQL being emitted when your `Word.each` is running. Is it something like `"select * from word"`? If so, Rails is pulling in 10,000 records to iterate over them one by one. If it is something like `"select * from word where id=1"` then for every record you have a database read followed by a write when you update the count. That is the scenario that the "Retrieving Multiple Objects in Batches" link will help fix.

Also, I am guessing that `content` is the text you are searching for, but I can't tell for sure. Is it possible you have duplicated text values causing you to do scans more than once for the same text? If so, select your records using a `unique` condition on that field and then update your counts for all matching records at one time.

Have you profiled your code to see if Ruby itself can help you pinpoint the problem? Modify your code a little to process 100 or 1000 records. Start the app with the `-r profile` flag. When the app exits profiler will output a table showing where time was spent.

What version of Rails are you running?

Comment: I can grab the substrings into an array/hash first, then add the count results to the array or hash, and write the results back to database after all the counting is done. You think it be faster, right?

Comment: Here is the 'top' report from the mac. The mac has a dualcore cpu,but it seems ruby can only use one of it (almost always 100% of the core): Processes: 91 total, 7 running, 84 sleeping, 387 threads               10:51:02
Load Avg: 1.29, 1.30, 1.25  CPU usage: 53.77% user, 5.66% sys, 40.56% idle
SharedLibs: 3716K resident, 7924K data, 0B linkedit.
MemRegions: 16869 total, 1302M resident, 31M private, 447M shared.
PhysMem: 753M wired, 2068M active, 5266M inactive, 8087M used, 104M free.
VM: 217G vsize, 1042M framework vsize, 1214206(0) pageins, 13989(0) pageouts

Comment: ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10]

Comment: Yes, the database is on the same machine. words table:CREATE TABLE `words` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  `cat` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_scan` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name_length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occurrence` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11570 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

Comment: Rather than add the additional information as comments, please add it to your original question by re-editing it. Indent it by four spaces to retain its formatting so its readable.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your entire "Word" table into a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), then do back-tracking since you said there are no delimiters in the text.

So for each character in the text, go down the Trie of words. If you hit a word, increment its count. "Going down the trie" involves three cases:

1. There's no node at this character. (If you're mid-search, pop the back-tracking stack)
2. There's a node at this character. (But it's not a Word)
3. There's a node at this character. (It's a Word - increment and "dirty")

Back-tracking is just keeping track of places you want to go after you've exhausted this "search" of the Trie, which is when you run out of nodes to visit. This will probably be each character you visit that is a root of the Trie.

After you've done this, you can then visit all the nodes you changed and just update the records they represent.

This will take some time to implement, but will surely be faster than each & scan.